# Windows phone place auto complete with cities names

Tags: google-maps, windows-phone-8.1

I am new in Windows Phone Development 8.1, I want to create a textbox which can perform place auto complete with cities name (India).
I tried to Install-Package gmaps-api-net 0.13.4 it gave me an error.

Error is:  You are trying to target 'Windows Phone, Version=8.1 but the package does not contain any assembly references or content file that are compatible with that framework.

Thanks & Regards,
Kaushik.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so this package will work , for that you have to create browser key from Google console and call like below

```
 string Entrypoint = String.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input={0}&types=geocode&sensor=false&key={1}", txtCityName.Text.Trim(), Constant.GOOGLE_KEY);
```

Comment: Hi Kushal, Can you please provide me detail code? I am new in Windows Phone Development, this is my first application.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a class shown below,

public static async Task GetResponse(string url)
        {
            try
            {
               // CustomLogger.printMsgOnConsole("Url in GetResponse =>" + url);
                //Create Client 
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                //CustomLogger.printMsgOnConsole("HttpClient obj created" + client);

```
            //Define URL. Replace current URL with your URL
            var uri = new Uri(url);
         //   CustomLogger.printMsgOnConsole("Create uri" + uri.ToString());
            //Call. Get response by Async
            var Response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
          //  CustomLogger.printMsgOnConsole("Calling get async");
            //Result & Code
            var statusCode = Response.StatusCode;
          //  CustomLogger.printMsgOnConsole("status code " + statusCode);
            //If Response is not Http 200 
            //then EnsureSuccessStatusCode will throw an exception
            Response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            //Read the content of the response.
            //In here expected response is a string.
            //Accroding to Response you can change the Reading method.
            //like ReadAsStreamAsync etc..
            var ResponseText = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

           // CustomLogger.printMsgOnConsole("Reponse in GetResponse =>" + ResponseText);

            return ResponseText;

        }
```

Now you need to give a call shown below,

string myhttp = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=" + txtCityName.Text.Trim() + "&types=geocode&sensor=false&key=" + mykey;

Kindly note 
1]. txtCityName is the textbox name.
2]. mykey is the Key generated by Google Api (Web Page).

This will return a json reponse.

Thanks,
Kaushik.